# Clicking a checkbox in a link causes the link to the followed — how can I avoid this?

Tags: html, css

I have checkbox insde a link. In all browsers except Chrome, when clicking on the checkbox you follow the link (instead of just having the checkbox become selected).

How do I avoid this behaviour?

Demo (hover over one of the product images to see the checkbox):

- http://livedemo07571.prestatrend.com/category.php?id_category=9

And here’s the code in question:

```
<a href="http://livedemo07571.prestatrend.com/product.php?id_product=25" class="product_img_link">
    <img src="http://livedemo07571.prestatrend.com/img/p/25-65-large.jpg" height="469" width="469" alt="Crew Neck Jumper" />

    <span class="new">New</span>

    <div class="right_block large">
        <h3 class="large">Crew Neck Jumper</h3>

        <span class="product_arrow"></span>
        <p class="availability_container"><span class="availability">Available</span></p>

        <span class="slash">&#47;</span>
        <p class="price_container"><span class="price" style="display: inline;">$2,390.00</span></p>

        <p class="compare large"><input type="checkbox" class="comparator" id="comparator_item_25" value="comparator_item_25" /> <label for="comparator_item_25">Select to compare</label></p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the checkbox must be within the link?

Comment: Ye, it is such design concept, if checkbox will not be there it will be not good looking.

Comment: Can I ask why you have so much inside of an anchor tag?  It is usually a bad idea to have so much markup inside of an anchor tag.  If you need it due to the :hover support in older browsers, I would suggest using javascript for that functionality and change your anchor to a div.  You can then add a click event on the div, and redirect if the target is not the checkbox.

Comment: I just need check checkbox and not going by the link when checked like in Chrome but not at other browsers!

Comment: @JohnSmith: we understand that. We’re saying that the best way to go about it is changing your HTML so that you don’t have the checkbox inside the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't valid HTML ([see report](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://livedemo07571.prestatrend.com/category.php?id_category=9&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)). The way to avoid this is, quite simply, to include only text or images inside an anchor tag, and move the checkbox outside. You could use some jQuery to add a click event to the box which would navigate to the next page.

Comment: It wouldn’t be valid HTML5 either — turns out you can’t have `<input>`s inside links in HTML5. (For, I guess, exactly the reason we see here.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want for-sure don't want to move it outside the `<a>` then you'd have to have an `onclick="return false;"` and add a listener with jQuery that toggles it when its clicked. I'm not sure if this would work in all browsers, and your best option is just to do it a standards friendly way.

Answer (score 1):

I think this happen because you have the Div (block element) is inside the A (inline element) tag and by default the event will bubble up soon as you click the checkbox.

Even if HTML 5 has made the exception for the A tag and now allow a block element to be nested within that inline element. To get that working the same accross all browser you'll have to wait they all support the html 5 features

1) try with a different doctype 
2) build the div outside the A has the link is not required to be executed

Comment: I just prepend div with checkbox outside a, thanks for everyone!